# Experiment with Embedded Solr in java and C

Tags: java, exception, solr, solrj

i'm using the following java code from  https://gist.github.com/nautical/9859452 :

```
              import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
              import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
              import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
              import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
              import org.apache.solr.common.params.CommonParams;
              import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;
              import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
              import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

              public class EmbeddedSolrExample{
              static CoreContainer container;
              static EmbeddedSolrServer server;

              public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
              String solrDir = "/Users/TheRoot/Downloads/solr-4.7.0/example/solr/";
              container = new CoreContainer(solrDir);
              container.load();
              server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1");
               }

             public static String query(String qstring){
             String output = null;
             ModifiableSolrParams solrParams = new ModifiableSolrParams();
             System.out.println(qstring);
             solrParams.add(CommonParams.Q, qstring);
             QueryResponse queryResponse = null;
             try {
             queryResponse = server.query(solrParams);
             } catch (SolrServerException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
               for (SolrDocument document : queryResponse.getResults()) {
              output += (document.getFieldValueMap().toString());
             }
             System.out.println(output);
             return output;
             }

            public static void entervalues(String Category,int Id, String Name) throws Exception{
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
            doc.addField("cat", Category);
            doc.addField("id", Id);
            doc.addField("name", Name);
            server.add(doc);
            server.commit(); // commit slows down .. do it after ~N inserts .. Seperate it
            }

            public static void close(){
            server.shutdown();
            container.shutdown();
            }
            }
```

I'm using sorl-4.9.0,i'm asking for Jars that i need it ,because i'm trying this code using solr-core-4.9.0.jar and 
solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar and i got this error

```
                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:              org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
                     at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<clinit>(CoreContainer.java:64)
                    at EmbeddedSolrExample.main(EmbeddedSolrExample.java:23)
                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
                   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                  ... 2 more
```

Comment: are there any configuration in solr xml files ??????

Comment: org.ibex.classgen.CGConst is related to sqlite as far as I can say. You might be missing something in your classpath that is required for what you're trying to use.

Comment: i 'm not using sqlite still now !!!!!!!!sincerely,i don't know what's the relation between this code and solr and sqlite ?????Can you explain more please

Comment: i don't see any relation with sqlite !!!

Comment: U ARE RIGHT ,i made some configuration, and i have another error,i edit it (see over)

Comment: The trace is saying you don't have slf4J on your classpath, do you have those included? are you using a build system? Try adding the slf4j api and nop libs to it. It sounds like you don't have all of Solr/SolrJ's dependencies, all the necessary jars should be in the dist.

Comment: i solved it again,and i have another error,So what i need is that what are the Jars that i must include ???????

Comment: Everything in the distribution

Comment: thanks oki iw ill include all the necessary jars from dist :)

Comment: i added all jars from the dist and other directory,and i have still errors,and the number of Jars is too big,are there a solution to reduce the number of jars ?????????